# Line follower robot with obstacle detection

Tags: sensor, line

I want to build a **line follower machine** for a competition and as I know the track will **include an obstacle** like a brick on the line that the machine will have to avoid coming back on the line.I will attach a basic image just for a better understanding.

[image]

Does anybody has an idea like what kind of sensor should I use for the best performance in terms of time? And just an idea how should I implement it.

My first idea that popped in my head it's an ultrasonic sensor but I'm afraid that it's too slow since my machine will have a high speed.And like checking all the time the response of the *ultrasonic sensor* it's not a good idea even though someone suggested me with an *interrupt rutine* could work.

Any idea is welcomed and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Time-of-flight sensor. 
STMicroelectronics makes some nice ones.

They work on the same principle as the ultrasonic sensor you mentioned, but with light instead of sound.

As far as i know they are quite reliable, precise, fast and have a relatively long range (up to some meters)

Adafruit has a breakout board with all the required additional components on-board: https://www.adafruit.com/product/3317

Note that i don't have never used one, but i've seen them in action here and there.

Comment: +1 Figuring out how to navigate round it is another matter :D